# Datatables plugin to search for header values

Tags: datatables

I am using jquery's dataTables plugin. I am having skills value as header in my table. I want to serch for users with specific skills. For example as shown in figure i want to search for users who have skill php. Then i should get the name of John. For css i should get name of Mona. The snapshot is here:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by implementing a custom filter for the datatable, as described [here](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html).

Before filtering you have to find, the index of the column you want to filter and check afterwards the value in each row.
This could look somewhat like this:

```html
<input type="text" id="skillFilter" />
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Skills</th>
            <th>PHP</th>
            <th>CSS</th>
            <th>HTML</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mona</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

script :

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data) {
        if (skillFilterColumnIndex != undefined) {
            //Get the data of each row
            var data = data[skillFilterColumnIndex] || "";
            return data > 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    });

$("#skillFilter").change(function() {
    var skill = $("#skillFilter").val().toLowerCase();
    //Find the column index with the skill to filter
    $.each($("#example thead th"), function(index, element) {
        if (index != 0 && element.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == skill) {
            skillFilterColumnIndex = index;
        }
    });
    table.fnDraw();
});
```

Comment: I think it is a great solution, but OP should be aware that it is dataTables 1.10.x only. For 1.9.x a little different approach is needed.  Here is a working fiddle for 1.10.x with the code above **http://jsfiddle.net/y9zsng2c/**

Comment: @davidkonrad Thank you for making a fiddle out of the code above. I wasn't able to do so :)